# get latest external file automaticly with project

Tags: version-control

I was create Project folder and Some sub folder that have solution under sub folders.

user A use solution A under sub folder A, user B use solution B under sub folder B (means that he map only folder b and work on it) and etc.

we have some common files that use on the all project (A,B,...) we can put them under the one folder for examople "Common" under the Project folder.

user A want to work with his project he get folder A but he need to Common folder files too. what to do?

like ewise user B want changes this file. and use to his project (B).

I want have automatic way to get external file with solution simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the common files under the Common folder together with solution, you can consider using batch script which contains two tf get commands:

tf.exe get /recursive $/SolutionA
tf.exe get /recursive $/Common

When running this batch script, both SolutionA and Common folder are downloaded.